# Discord.js clear command doesn't accept numbers

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I used a template I found on the internet to make my clear command and here is what I've done so far:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "clear",
  description: "clear",

  execute(message, args) {
    const amount = args.join(" ");

    if (!amount)
      return message.reply(
        "You haven't given an amount of messages which should be deleted!"
      );
    if (isNaN(amount))
      return message.reply("The amount parameter isn`t a number!");
    if (amount > 100)
      return message.reply("You can`t delete more than 100 messages at once!");
    return message.reply("You have to delete at least 1 message!");

    message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount }).then((messages) => {
      message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
    });
  },
};
```

Even if I wrote a number after the _clear command it says this :"The amount parameter isn`t a number!" which is the message that the bot supposed to send if someone types something which isn't a number. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: try to log what amount is before `isNaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your amount is always received as `args[0]`, you could parse this string and test if the result is an integer like this :

```
if(!parseInt(args[0], 10)) return message.channel.send("Not a number");
```

Comment: `isNaN()` also does the trick, it's prob more the fact `args.join(" ")`

Comment: @Karizma you're right. At least OP will have the opportunity to make a choice ;p